# Determine among all the triangles with equal perimeter 2p the one with the greatest area

Tags: calculus

Determine among all the triangles with equal perimeter 2p the one with the greatest area.
I need to solve the problem but I still haven't found the right way to solve it

Comment: Why $2p$?  Why the factor of $2$?  How would your problem differ if you had instead simplified and asked about perimeter $p$?  And what have you tried?

Comment: Area $T={\sqrt {s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}} $ where s=(a+b+c)/2.  Using elem. calc. T max when all sides =

Answer (score -1):

If we are going to use differentiation to get the answer for this it's going to be a real hassle. So instead we will use a neat inequality, which is the AM-GM Inequality.

Let $a,b$ and $c$ be the sides of a triangle with a perimeter of $2p$. By Heron's Formula we have $Area = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ where $s$ is the semi-perimeter. If we substitute $p$ as the semi-perimeter we get

$$Area = \sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$$

Here $p$ is a constant so what we really want to maximize is the product $(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)$.

Let $x=(p-a), y=(p-b)$ and $z=(p-c)$. The AM-GM inequality states that $\displaystyle\frac{x+y+z}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{xyz}$. By substitution we get

$$\frac{(p-a)+(p-b)+(p-c)}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$$

$$\implies \frac{3p-(a+b+c)}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$$

$$\implies \frac{p}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)} \ (\because a+b+c = perimeter = 2p)$$

Thus we can see that if $\displaystyle a=b=c=\frac{2p}{3}$ we get the maximum for the product $(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)$ which is $\displaystyle\frac{8p^3}{27}$. Therefor the maximum area is $\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{8p^4}{27}}$